# Warning: Division By Zero Working on PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, loops, division, zero

I am doing a calculation with an array which is drawn from mysql and the problem is "division by zero" warning

I am running a loop over this statment

```
$v = (($v - $valuei)/($valuei) * 100);
```

Here $v is is changing (let's say from 100 to 150 e.g 100, 101, 102, 103,...,150) and $valuei is the intial value of $v (i.e 100) So, when the calculation will start first output should be zero and I want that zero then why it gives a warning "Division By Zero " and also makes all the "$v" values equal to zero.

Comment: Why on earth are you multiplying by a numeric string? I mean, sure it'll work anyway... but why?

Comment: Integers are too mainstream I guess :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning suggests, that $valuei is, in fact, 0 during one of the runs.

Are you sure, that $valuei is initialized properly?
To get rid of the warning, you should add do:

```
if($valuei != 0) {
    $v = (($v - $valuei)/($valuei) * '100');
}
```

This way, the warning should disappear.

Comment: Thank You Anthony!
You were right, Error was due to O value of $valuei itself.....
Everything working perfectly now......

Answer (score 1):

If `$valuei` is initially set to `$v` then on the first iteration `(x - x) = 0` and thus, you are dividing by zero (or rather, are trying to divide 0 by *something*, which is a mistake).

Without seeing the rest of the loop I can only speculate, but I suspect the direction you're probably heading for is to start the loop at index '1' instead of '0'.

Also, why multiply by '100' instead of 100?